# Laravel Polymorphic Relations problems

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

in this [link](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql) suggested to do not use `Polymorphic Relations`

for example for this Sql commands we must be without `FOREIGN KEY`

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (

    comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    comment TEXT NOT NULL,

    issue_type VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL CHECK (issue_type IN (`Bugs`, `Features`)),

    issue_id INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY issue_id REFERENCES ???

);
```

then we must be have :

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (

    comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    comment TEXT NOT NULL,

    issue_type VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL CHECK (issue_type IN (`Bugs`, `Features`)),

    issue_id INT NOT NULL,

);
```

this command have problem for using `JOIN` or using simultaneously `JOIN`s such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Comments c

LEFT JOIN Bugs b ON (c.issue_type = 'Bugs' AND c.issue_id = b.issue_id)

LEFT JOIN Features f ON (c.issue_type = 'Features' AND c.issue_id = f.issue_id);
```

those problems is only for `SELECT` other problem are: `UPDATE`, `DELETE`

whats laravel way to resolve this problems?

**UPDATE:**
how to find post owner now?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has polymorphic relations, see here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Your database table is setup the same (except you need to use `commentable_id` and `commetnable_type` to work with the following code sample), and in your models do something like this:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}

class Bug extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Comment', 'commentable');
    }

}

class Feature extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Comments', 'commentable');
    }

}
```

You can then use this like:

```
$bug = Bug::find(1)->comments();
```

You can also go the other way, so if you just grab a list of comments, you can then get the owner of that comment, without knowing what it is yet:

```
$comment = Comment::find(1);

$commentable = $comment->commentable; 
// this will load the bug or feature that the comment belongs to
```

Comment: how to find post owner now?

Comment: updated the answer to add a section to the bottom to also outline this